# How to disable CSP (content security policy) for UIWebview and WKWebview

Tags: uiwebview, wkwebview, content-security-policy

We want to run some JavaScript for the web pages that loaded in our webview, but some of them enable CSP block JS. Is there anyway we can disable CSP in UIWebview and WKWebview?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way to turn the Content Security Policy off or bypass it through faking a response header.

Although, even if something like this was possible, Apple could possibly deny the submission to the store as it could be a potential security violation.